# Textures not displaying - Cocos2D 2.0 Alpha

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, opengl-es-2.0

I know Cocos2d 2.0 is in alpha and will obviously have certain issues with it.  I am trying to convert several projects to use OpenGL 2.0 for multiple reasons, but am having one very strange issue.

When I start up a scene, my textures load as desired and everything works great.  I then display some Apple UI elements that allow me to quit the scene.  The scene and its view controller are deallocated, the director is told to end, and I return to another view. Then I press a UIButton that launches the scene again.  The scene begins again and runs, but no textures are visible.  Fonts load and display, audio loads and plays, but no textures are visible.  When dumping info from the CCTextureCache, I can see that the desired textures are available in the cache ( [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] dumpCachedTextureInfo] ).  I have also tried clearing the cache before the scene is relaunched.  No matter what, I can not see any textures or add nodes to the scene.

There could be something wrong with how I reset the scene, or how the EAGLView is setup.  Here is the code for starting said scene from a View Controller:

(void)startGame {

```
CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
EAGLView *glView = [EAGLView viewWithFrame:[self.view bounds]];

[director setOpenGLView:glView];

[self setView:glView];
[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] removeUnusedTextures];
//[CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene:[Cocos2DChipmunkScene scene]];
}
```

Then, the scene is quit, and the following is called:

`CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];`

[[director openGLView] removeFromSuperview];

[director end];

The above startGame method is called again when I try to start the game again.  This is the point where no textures are displayed.

Let me know if I need to provide more details on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation is to not shut down the director and keep the openGLView in the hierarchy, just set it as hidden: `openGLView.hidden = YES;`

You can start and stop cocos2d via `[[CCDirector sharedDirector] startAnimation]` respectively stopAnimation.